# Converting C code to Java

Tags: java, c, pointers

Can someone explain to me what the two pieces of code below do, and what the equivalent would look like in Java?

```
double* ptr;
    ptr = (double*)malloc(10*_R_CONST*sizeof(double)+2048);
```

I presumed from my limited knowledge of C that it's declaring a pointer ptr, setting the size of the pointer?

This is what the calls look like later in the same file

```
ptr[10*n+2]=-RadtoMOA(atan(y/x));
ptr[10*n+0]=x/3;                            
ptr[10*n+1]=y*12;                           
ptr[10*n+2]=-RadtoMOA(atan(y/x));           
ptr[10*n+3]=t+dt;
```

---

There is another similar function, again I'm unfamiliar with C. The two lines with asterisks are the lines I am wondering about particularly.

```
double GetRange(double* sln, int yardage){
    **double size=sln[_R_CONST*10+1];**
    if (yardage<size){
        **return sln[10*yardage];**
    }
    else return 0;
}
```

---

For the first portion of this question here's the full code, incl. the excerpts above.

```
double* ptr;
    ptr = (double*)malloc(10*_R_CONST*sizeof(double)+2048);

double t=0;
double dt=0.5/Vi;
double v=0;
double vx=0, vx1=0, vy=0, vy1=0;
double dv=0, dvx=0, dvy=0;
double x=0, y=0;

double headwind=HeadWind(WindSpeed, WindAngle);
double crosswind=CrossWind(WindSpeed, WindAngle);

double Gy=GRAVITY*cos(DegtoRad((Angle + ZAngle)));
double Gx=GRAVITY*sin(DegtoRad((Angle + ZAngle)));

vx=Vi*cos(DegtoRad(ZAngle));
vy=Vi*sin(DegtoRad(ZAngle));

y=-SightHeight/12;

int n=0;
for (t=0;;t=t+dt){

    vx1=vx, vy1=vy; 
    v=pow(pow(vx,2)+pow(vy,2),0.5);
    dt=0.5/v;

    // Compute acceleration using the drag function retardation 
    dv = retard(DragFunction,DragCoefficient,v+headwind);       
    dvx = -(vx/v)*dv;
    dvy = -(vy/v)*dv;

    // Compute velocity, including the resolved gravity vectors.    
    vx=vx + dt*dvx + dt*Gx;
    vy=vy + dt*dvy + dt*Gy;



    if (x/3>=n){
        ptr[10*n+0]=x/3;                            // Range in yds
        ptr[10*n+1]=y*12;                           // Path in inches
        ptr[10*n+2]=-RadtoMOA(atan(y/x));           // Correction in MOA
        ptr[10*n+3]=t+dt;                           // Time in s
        ptr[10*n+4]=Windage(crosswind,Vi,x,t+dt);   // Windage in inches
        ptr[10*n+5]=RadtoMOA(atan(ptr[10*n+4]));    // Windage in MOA
        ptr[10*n+6]=v;                              // Velocity (combined)
        ptr[10*n+7]=vx;                         // Velocity (x)
        ptr[10*n+8]=vy;                         // Velocity (y)
        ptr[10*n+9]=0;                              // Reserved
        n++;    
    }   

    // Compute position based on average velocity.
    x=x+dt*(vx+vx1)/2;
    y=y+dt*(vy+vy1)/2;

    if (fabs(vy)>fabs(3*vx)) break;
    if (n>=R_CONST+1) break;
}

ptr[10*_R_CONST+1]=(double)n;

*Solution = ptr;

return n;
```

}

Comment: Don't use `**` to highlight lines of code.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because stack overflow is not a translation or "explain my code" service.

Comment: You are not translating an algorithm or similar code, where you can have a reasonable attempt of doing line-by-line analysis.  It is an entire body of code -- you should try to figure out what the code is supposed to do, on a high-level, and implement it from scratch in Java.  You aren't going to get far trying to get a `malloc` working in Java, since there is no such thing.

Comment: I think asking about what certain $UNFAMILIAR_LANGUAGE statements do, explained in terms of equivalent constructs in $FAMILIAR_LANGUAGE, is legitimate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
double* ptr;
ptr = (double*)malloc(10*_R_CONST*sizeof(double)+2048);
```

This is the C way of allocating an array dynamically at runtime, the Java equivalent is

```
double[] ptr = new double[10*_R_CONST+256];
```

(Note that Java does not need the `sizeof(double)` factor, since it allocates objects, not bytes. For the same reason, the 2048 byte buffer shrinks to 256 doubles.)

Similar, the method declaration

```
double GetRange(double* sln, int yardage)
```

would translate to

```
double GetRange(double[] sln, int yardage)
```

The other lines you pointed out are simply accesses to elements of this array of doubles.

```
*Solution = ptr;
```

You didn't show the declaration of `Solution` nor asked about it, but my guess is that `Solution` is a `double **` and passed as argument. There is no direct Java equivalent for this (though it can be simulated); what it does is to store the address of the allocated array into a variable provided by the caller of the method.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is helpful. I don't have much C experience so my understanding of the syntax is limited. Just needed some pointers. ha.